# Haskell Terminology: Part of type signature following constraints

Tags: haskell

Many type signatures in Haskell are of the following form:

```
a :: (B) => C
```

As I understand it, the term "type signature" refers to the entire construct `a :: (B) => C`, and `B` (if present) is called a "constraint".  However, I'm not sure how to unambiguously refer to the remainder of the type signature, `C`.

**Is there any standard name for the part of the type signature located to the right of any constraints?**

A few naive searches came up with nothing.  So far, here are my best attempts, but it would be nice to have a term that is both concise and unambiguous:

- "The part of the type signature after any constraints"
- "The constraint-free part of the type signature"
- In some cases, it might be clear from the context to say "the remainder of the type signature"

To make this more concrete, here's an example from the Prelude:

```
mapM :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]
```

Relative to the notation used above, the identifier `mapM` corresponds to `a`, the constraint `Monad m` corresponds to `B`, and `(a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]` corresponds to `C`.  I'm looking for a word/phrase that unambiguously would refer to the part of the type signature following the `=>`, namely `(a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]`.

Comment: The thing `Show a => a -> a` is called a type. So is the thing `a -> a`. Traditionally, the word "type" refers to things of kind `*` - the kind of types. For example, `Maybe` is not a type, it's a type constructor (it's kind is `* -> *`). Neither is `Show a` for example (whose kind is `Constraint`, the kind of class constraints). However, depending on the situation, it is perfectly valid to use "type" to refer to things of *any* kind - (i.e. types of kind `*`, types of kind `Constraint`, etc). If you need to be explicit, `Show a` is a 'constraint' or 'context', `a -> a` is a 'type'.

Comment: And `forall a . Show a => a -> a` is a polytype (ran out of room). This language is not universal, but appears in many places, for example the formal specification of the type system.

Comment: There might be no widely used term for that. E.g., the Haskell report says "In general, we use cx to denote a context and we write cx => t to indicate the type t restricted by the context cx." using the very generic term "type". https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-630004.1

Comment: This is idiosyncratic GHC nomenclature, but in the type `forall a. (Show b, Read c) => d`, the full thing is called a sigma type, `(Show b, Read c) => d` is a rho type, `(Show b, Read c)` is a theta type and `d` is a tau type.

Answer (score 1):

When I think of "class constraints", I think of "superclass constraints" that appear on the left hand side of a class definition:

```
class (Functor a) => Applicative a
```

I call constraints on a *function* just "constraints". In both cases, the constraints don't actually need to arise from a class. For example, we can have equality constraints:

```
f :: (a ~ Int) => a -> a -> a
```

The "C" portion you refer to (in the example above, `a -> a -> a`) is called the "head" (as in ["instance head"](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/6.4-latest/docs/html/users_guide/type-extensions.html#id3144883)).

Comment: Actually, this does not answer the question.

Comment: I think it answers the question. He asked what the "C" portion is. Care to suggest an improvement?

Comment: The `C` in your example would be the part `a -> a -> a` in the larger type `(a ~ Int) => a -> a -> a`, and not the part `(a ~ Int)`. The OP is using `C` for the _right_ hand side of `=>` in types, while the letter `C` is commonly used for the _left_ part.

Comment: "Head" is already quite overloaded... To disambiguate this, would you say something like "the head of a type signature"?  Also, could you provide any links that show "head" being used in the way you suggest?  Searching for "Haskell head of type signature" doesn't seem to produce many relevant results.

Comment: Just in case there was any confusion, I've tried to update the question to more precisely identify the part of the signature that I'm talking about.  I've also changed "class constraints" to "constraints", since as Eric pointed out, there can be other types of constraints.

Comment: @chi I completely agree with your assessment of the OP; I'm did try to say that the RHS (the "C" part) is called the head. Perhaps I can be clearer...

Comment: @alev Updated the answer.

Comment: @Eric Thanks for the update.  It looks like that term is specific to the RHS of a constrained instance declaration, where the semantics are significantly different.  (In my understanding, the RHS of a constrained instance declaration is a type class followed by one or more types, whereas the RHS of a constrained type signature is just a bare/unconstrained type.)  Because of this, and because I haven't found any examples of "head" being used for a type signature the same way it is used for instance declarations, I would be wary of using this term.  But it's good to know it exists.